# After removing pi-hole my eth0 does not working at all

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I uninstalled pi-hole from my **raspberry pi 4** and got lost ethernet connection. Only orange led is working.
Ifconfig shows only lo, but with flag -a it does show eth0. I can run ifconfig eth0 up and green led light start flashing, but i still cant get a ip address. What can I do in this case?

Comment: You could try assigning a *static* IP address using the the command `ifconfig eth0 <ipaddr>`.

Comment: @sawdust I'm able to see eth0 in inconfig now, but seems like I having some kind of troubles with DNS because when I run ping google.com im getting temporary failure in name resolution. But my /etc/resolv.conf has nameserver 8.8.8.8

Comment: *"I'm able to see eth0 in inconfig now, but ..."* -- Stop the summations, and provide details!  Seems like you're conflating WAN and LAN.  Describe your LAN connection to the router, and your router configuration.